# why is waiting time of the website is too high

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, vs-web-site-project

I have a WordPress webiste and its waiting time is too high I have done the optimization using autoptimizer and use the gzip compression code in the htaccess file for the compression.

please help me out is this the issue from the my end or is this server issue

I am placing the link of the recent test fone using Gtmatrix fro my website:
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/unicommerce.com/vein49uQ

help me out with the valuable suggestion that I can do for the optimization of speed and scoores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server sends the data with an outdated HTTP protocol and is quite slow generally.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Try to implement the HTTP2 Protocol on your server because it is capable of multithreading. Then the combining of css files and scripts and move them to footer and so on gets obsolete.

What kind of hosting do you have?

[image]

And there are some typical problems, like render blocking ressources and so on to eleminate:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Funicommerce.com

Regards Tom

Comment: it's on amazon web hosting don't know why the server response is too low and waiting time so high

Answer (score 0):

- You need to compress JS , CSS and HTML files using htaccess files
- Combine CSS into one CSS so all css will not load
- Block unnessesary JS and CSS files to load
- Add some browser cache plugin
- EWWW plugin for image compress

Visit  https://samaxes.com/2008/04/htaccess-gzip-and-cache-your-site-for-faster-loading-and-bandwidth-saving/

Answer (score 0):

first thing you can check that which file taking longer time for load and apply defer or async keyword on link so your loading can improve